Fixing yaml indentation with python
I'm manipulating existing yaml file (CloudFormation template) and copying needed resources into a new file.
The thing is, I'm getting part of the resource in a new line - not according to the correct indentation.
It seems the 3rd line is not adhering to the indentation configuration.
I've checked Python modules: yaml-indent, ruamel.yaml config, yamlfix, pyymal and off course our AI friends.. but the issue persists.
How can I write it in a correct manner ?
Code snippet:
    with open(entrypath, 'r') as magic:
        yaml_object = yaml.load(magic, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
        # print(yaml_object['Resources'][rscItem])

        with open('{}_Restore.yaml'.format(resourcename), 'a+') as s:
            s.write('  {}:'.format(rscItem))
            s.write('\n')
            s.write('    {}'.format(yaml.safe_dump(yaml_object['Resources'][rscItem], default_flow_style=False, indent=4)))

(I am aware of the spaces in s.write('    {}', that part is working as it should (-:)
Yaml file:
How it looks like:
Resources:
  defaulteventbus:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
Properties:
  Name: default
  Tags: []
Type: AWS::Events::EventBus
UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain

  LambdaEventSourceMapping:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
Properties:
  BatchSize: 1
  BisectBatchOnFunctionError: true
  DestinationConfig:
    OnFailure:
      Destination:
        Ref: SNSTopicName
  Enabled: true

How it should looks like:
Resources:
  defaulteventbus:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      Name: default
      Tags: []
    Type: AWS::Events::EventBus
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain

  LambdaEventSourceMapping:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BatchSize: 1
      BisectBatchOnFunctionError: true
      DestinationConfig:
        OnFailure:
          Destination:
            Ref: SNSTopicName
      Enabled: true

Updated code that @Michael wrote:
    with open(entrypath, 'r') as magic:
            yaml_object = yaml.load(magic, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
            # print(yaml_object['Resources'][rscItem])

    with open('{}_Restore.yaml'.format(resourcename), 'a+') as s:
            data = {rscItem: yaml_object['Resources'][rscItem]}
            text = yaml.safe_dump(data, default_flow_style=False, indent=2)
            s.write(textwrap.indent(text, ' ' * 2))



Do not try to manually format yaml files. You're already using the yaml module. Just use that instead. Create the entire dict/list in memory and then safe_dump() the entire blob.

@Dunes Thanks for the idea! tried it , but it doesn't look as it should as well.

@soBusted show us what you tried

@soBusted , there are a couple of things that could be cleared up in your question. Does the yaml code after "Yaml file: How it looks like:" refer to your input yaml file or the current output you are producing. If it is not the input file, then it would be very useful to see what the input looks like. Second, does the code snippet you provided refer to your attempt to solve your problem, or to the initial producer of your input yaml file?

For debugging, you could try using the pprint module. If it does not eg. pprint(data, indent='  '). If the output doesn't really look like what you might expect, then it's likely because you have not built your data blob correctly in the first place.

@Dunes Thank you for your help, you're awesome.

The question is not totally clear, but maybe this will help:
import textwrap
import yaml

with open('source.yaml', 'r') as magic:
    source = yaml.load(magic, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
    for rscItem in source['Resources'].keys():
        with open('{}_Restore.yaml'.format(rscItem), 'a+') as s:
            data = {rscItem: source['Resources'][rscItem]}
            text = yaml.safe_dump(data, default_flow_style=False, indent=4)
            s.write(textwrap.indent(text, ' ' * 4)

Assuming you have input file source.yaml
Resources:
  defaulteventbus:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      Name: default
      Tags: []
    Type: AWS::Events::EventBus
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain

  LambdaEventSourceMapping:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BatchSize: 1
      BisectBatchOnFunctionError: true
      DestinationConfig:
        OnFailure:
          Destination:
            Ref: SNSTopicName
      Enabled: true

the script above outputs files
    defaulteventbus:
        DeletionPolicy: Retain
        Properties:
            Name: default
            Tags: []
        Type: AWS::Events::EventBus
        UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain

and
    LambdaEventSourceMapping:
        DeletionPolicy: Retain
        Properties:
            BatchSize: 1
            BisectBatchOnFunctionError: true
            DestinationConfig:
                OnFailure:
                    Destination:
                        Ref: SNSTopicName
            Enabled: true


Amazing! You got it just right, I've made some adjustments to your code , and now it is perfect!

Glad to hear that! I don't know your use case, but please try to follow @Dunes advice and don't process YAML as plain text. This can lead to dangerous errors.
